# Drupal - Restrict permissions to portions of site

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, access-control

I'm a drupal newb and trying to figure out permission/access control. I would like to set up a user role that would allow a user modify everything under a menu block. Does anyone know of any modules or tutorials that would help out? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [menu_access](http://drupal.org/project/menu_access) module.

Comment: Thanks. This looks like what I need. Unfortunately, the site menus have disappeared now that I've turned the module on. Need to play with the configuration some more.

Comment: Of course the first thing I should have done after installing the menu_access module is rebuild permissions. Things seem back to normal.